# A clarification about 1 as proper divisor.

Tags: definition, divisibility

Should "1" be considered as a proper divisor?Clearly,internet says yes but our textbook still follow that one is not a proper divisor.

Comment: Define "proper divisor".

Comment: For all numbers greater than one, 1 is a proper divisor, but a trivial one. Perhaps your textbook is defining "proper" as "non-trivial".

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the author's view, some authors say $0$ does not belong to the set of natural numbers, but some authors do.